# VBA Array/Collection of Objects (Pictures)

Tags: excel, vba

The following VBA code copies from excel a named range for a table as a picture and pastes it into a word document as a picture using content controls. The content control name is the same as the named range in excel.

The following snippet of code works efficiently from going between excel and word each time when there are 10 pictures or less.  However, some of my documents have 50+ named range as pictures to transfer and can take 1 minute+ to transfer all pictures.  Is there a way to use array/collections to store all pictures from excel and the retrieve them from the array/collection and paste in word?  Would this be faster? Or is there another way to make the process more efficient?

```
Set tTable = Range(CCtrl.Title)
tTable.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

Set wdbmRange = wdDoc.ContentControls(CCtrl.ID)
If Occ.Type = wdContentControlPicture Then
If Occ.Range.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then Occ.Range.InlineShapes(1).Delete
wdDoc.ContentControls(CCtrl.ID).Range.Paste
```

Comment: Could you provide some background?  Why are you copying so many pictures from Excel to Word?  Will this be ongoing or a one-time thing? How many documents in total?  Why are you putting them into Word (an even less efficient places to store large numbers of images than Excel is.)

Comment: I produce financial reports for equity investors. The use of excel is to produce the tables with the financial analysis that are copied as a picture and pasted into word to produce the report. I developed the code above because I got tired of doing it manually. Depending on the complexity of the investment the number of tables will vary.

Comment: Copying ranges as pictures to Word (using the Clipboard) can get slow, but you might be able to speed it up by not displaying the operation on screen (make Word hidden). This will get much faster if you [copy as text](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/5/22/copy-paste-an-excel-table-into-microsoft-word-with-vba)